# @Pattern - String java bean validation

Tags: regex, bean-validation

My bean has a property called description.
I need to write a regex to verify if there is any , in the string then it should be enclosed in double quotes.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[,?""]*$") did not work for me.
```

Comment: If there is any what? Comma `,`?

Answer (score 1):

The following will accept any description that does not contain a comma, regardless of whether it is surrounded by quotes. It also accepts any descriptions that contain a comma as long as they also are surrounded by quotes.

- Valid: "A,B"
- Valid: "A,B,C"
- Valid: AB
- Valid: "AB"
- Invalid: A,B

If that's the case then the following should work:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^([^,]*|\"[^,]*(,[^,]*)+\")*$")
```

Here's a breakdown of the significant parts of the regex:

- ^ Matches start of line
- [^,]* Matches zero or more non-commas
- (,[^,]*)+ Matches at least one group of characters starting with a comma and followed by zero or more non-comma characters.
- $ Matches end of line

The other ()* components just mean that this pattern can be repeated zero or more times.

Comment: Valid: "A,B" Invalid: A,B

Comment: If a comma exists in the description then the whole description has to be surrounded by quotes. If no comma is present then the surrounding quotes are not required.  

Are these correct?  

Valid: AB
Valid: "AB"
Valid: "A,B"
Invalid: A,B

Comment: I've updated the pattern based on the new info and how I think you're suggesting the validation should work.

Comment: The string itself is invalid as you are using double quotes in between.

Comment: Easy enough to fix. The editor I use tries to be smart about copying text from inside strings by unescaping escaped printable-characters.

Comment: Strange... it works properly in my test bed. If you copy-pasted into an IDE are you sure it didn't add extra backslashes? There should only be one before each " character.

Comment: @mohan141 I'm using hibernate-validator version 4.3.1.Final by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes inside your double code which will not be accepted as a valid Java String , try to set \ before the nested double quotes , the [] is an OR operator in regex which means one of the specified element iside the bracket . so i think for your requirement the pattern should be :

```
@Pattern(regexp = "((\",\")|.*)*$")
```

Comment: It did not work.My string may or may not contain a comma(,).If it is present it should be enclosed in double quote.

Comment: @mohan141 even this ?